# What is exponential accuracy? How many types of accuracy are there?

Tags: functions, approximation-theory

I am reading and working on some function approximation methods. I did not quite understand **"Exponential Accuracy"** which is mentioned in multiple works in literature. I searched the internet only to find the mentions about it but not a definition about it. There are other types of accuracies like linear, logarithmic and quadratic... It sounds something simple or isn't it that simple? A good reference will help and thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the usage?

Comment: Is this in the frame of speed of convergence of sequences ?

Comment: It can be any learning and convergence setting for function approximation. One example is https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19950004400.pdf. I do not see such accuracies compared as a study in itself (is such study needed in the first place?)